# Terminal Server Licensing Failing to Connect

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

I have a server that is not connecting to the terminal server licensing server.  The licensing server happens to be the same server.  This just started happening within the last week.  I have not made any changes to the server nor have I installed any new software.

When I first boot up the server I get the `Terminal Server Licensing encountered a problem and needed to close` message.  Here are the details:

[image]

Via Terminal Server Licensing I tried to Connect to the server via its IP address as well as the name and I get the `Windows cannot connect to a licensing server`:

[image]

Looking at the Event Viewer I see the following errors:

***Under System***

[image]
[image]

***Under Application***

[image]
[image]
[image]

**What can I do to correct whatever issue is stopping the terminal server licensing from working?**

Comment: Recent updates perhaps?

Comment: it is set to update automatically

Comment: Right...a recent windows update could have broken something. I'd start with checking any updates installed in the past week just to see.

Comment: would i just uninstall them?

Comment: That would be a decent troubleshooting step. One at a time until you find the problem one. It may be worth looking up the updates to see if they apply to anything that would affect terminal services.

Comment: The last time the server was updated was on 10/9/2013.  I noticed the problem started to occur on 10/18/2013.  So, I don't think an update caused it.  Since it was working for roughly a week after any updates were installed.

Comment: Ah, that rules updates out then. I'm as stumped as you are.

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall the TS License Server role and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: if I do that will I have to reinstall all of the licenses?

Comment: Probably, but you do have them handy, right?

Comment: No not exactly, I have half of them handy.